# How to inflate SupportActionBar menu from outside Activity

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

I decoupled view from my Activity and I have a separate class for all UI related operations. One operation I want to implement there is to inflate menu for Action Bar. I try doing things like these, but none of it works.

```
fun displayMenu() {

    rootView.toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.my_menu)

    rootView.toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener { item ->
        if (item.itemId == R.id.action_one) {
            listener.onActionOne()
        }

        true
    }
}
```

I tried this:

```
activity.menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.my_menu, rootView.toolbar.menu)
```

and this:

```
rootView.toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.my_menu)
```

But none of these gets the job done. How can I inflate this menu?

Comment: Do you set your toolbar as supportActionBar before you inflate the menu ?

Comment: @MelihAksoy Yes, I do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was all my silly mistake.

```
activity.menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.my_menu, rootView.toolbar.menu)
```

Works perfectly fine. Just remember to call it during or after Activity.onCreateOptionMenu. Complete example to make it works is something like:

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Inject
MyView myView;

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(myView.getRootView());
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    myView.displayMenu();
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

}

public class MyViewImpl implements MyView {

    @Override
    public void displayMenu() {
        activity.getMenuInflater().inflate(
            R.menu.categories_modification_menu,
            rootView.findViewById(R.id.toolbar).getMenu()
        )
    }

}
```

I used displayMenu() from Activity.onCreate before... Sorry for wasting your time, especially I did not post this part as I thought it is irrelevant to the question...

Comment: Remind yourself to accept your own answer. This is both to mark it as closed and to provide a clear answer for others ;) Glad you found.

Comment: Hey, I will remember, but I can do it after two days :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to code in Kotlin. 
This is how I do in Java. Just Override `onCreateOptionsMenu()` method in your Activity class.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my_menu, menu);

}
```

Comment: Hi, I know how to do it from Activity. The question is how to do it from outside...

Comment: Are you writing some kind of Utility method ?. I guess you need context object then.

Comment: @RohotSingh I already solved it, it was a silly mistake of mine.